# How to make a synchronous call in angular 5?

Tags: angular, typescript, service, angular-services, angular-components

So, I was trying to get the solution of this problem. But, somehow I am unable to do so, May be because of the lack of knowledge in angular 5.
This is my service:

```
GetCurrentUserData(): Observable<ResponseData> {
    return this.http.get<ResponseData>(ApplicationURLS.GetCurrentUserInformation)
        .map(response => {
            return response;
        });
    //.catch(error => this.handleError(error));
}
```

This is my component:

```
public GetCurrentUserInformation(): any {

        return this.loginService.GetCurrentUserData().subscribe(data => { return data; });
    }
```

Here I am trying to access the data:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
        debugger;                
        this.responseData = this.GetCurrentUserInformation();
        if (this.responseData.code != responseCodes.success) {
            this.googleInit();
        }

    }
```

When I check the this.responseData it is always returning this instead I want data:
[image]

I just want to make a sync call so I can get the data immediately.

I also tried to use the do() in service but its returning do() is not a function.

Comment: I think async/await can be a best case here 

Comment: @malbarmawi yup

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This can be simplified by using `async/await`

```
public GetCurrentUserInformation(): Promise<any>{
    return this.loginService.GetCurrentUserData().toPromise()
}
```

ngAfterViewInit

```
async ngAfterViewInit() {    
        this.responseData = await this.GetCurrentUserInformation(); // ‍♂️ 
        if (this.responseData.code != responseCodes.success) {
            this.googleInit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Emanuele Bellini : what is this  "this.responseData.code != responseCodes.success"  do await send any code field ?

Comment: @SwapnilM No: await allows to get the result instead of the promise, like it was a synchronous call. So I can guess it was a field returned by GetCurrentUserData(), which is of type `any`.

Answer (score 8):

Subscribe to `GetCurrentUserData()` the http call is async (every browser api call is async, because the javascript engine runs in a single thread (google for browser event loop for more, this is not an angular issue))

```
this.GetCurrentUserInformation().subscribe((data: ResponseData) => {
        if (this.responseData.code != responseCodes.success) {
            this.googleInit();
        }
});
```

Comment: Exactly, I just realized that and made changes accordingly now it is working as expected.

Comment: you forget to set the `this.responseData = data` 

Answer (score 5):

Asynchronous functions cannot be called synchronously, because they are asynchronous.

`subscribe` generally shouldn't performed in methods that are expected to be chained. Even if it should, an observable and not a subscription should be returned from a method (a subscription can be additionally saved to be unsubscribed on destruction).

`GetCurrentUserInformation` method is redundant because it is just a wrapper for service call. The code can be refactored to:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loginService.GetCurrentUserData().subscribe(data => {
        this.responseData = data;
        if (this.responseData.code != responseCodes.success) {
            this.googleInit();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yup,+1 I was meant to complete the function first. But, yes as you pointed out and G.viteli helps me I am able to understand it now.

Comment:  agreed but you can use async/await will look as it 's as asynchronous

Comment: This will not be a synchronous call and it is not for you to decide that the **public** method should be refactored into ngAfterViewInit because it is exposed to the outer world for a meaning (hopefully ;) )

Answer (score 5):

To make sure async calls are executed before processing response you may use Observable.forkJoin() from ReactiveX.

```js
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
```

```js
Observable.forkJoin(
    this.http.get('/links.json').map((response:Response) => response.json()),
    this.http.get('/bookmarks.json').map((response:Response) => response.json())
).subscribe(
    data => {
      this.links = data[0]
      this.bookmarks = data[1]
    },
    error => console.error(error)
);
```

subscribe() function's onNext handler will execute when all HTTP requests complete successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Use **synchronous** http request as below

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', "https://domain/api", false);  
request.send(null);
const response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
```

Would not be able to take advantage of DI using `HttpClient` and hence should be used absolutely when required.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to make the call synchronous is to use complete method of subscribe.

> source$.subscribe({ next: doSomething, error: doSomethingElse,
> complete: lol }).

if we subscribe something and want to do some operation after completing this subscribe then we can write the code in complete.

for detail reading
https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments

Answer (score 0):

there is no direct way to make a synchronous call, however you can do the following procedure (this code is written in angular 7).

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {
  Request1result:Object;
  Request2result:Object;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

   ngOnInit() 
   {
    this.http.get("URL1").subscribe((res)=>{
      this.Request1result=res;
      this.after1(); // execution will move to next request only when first is done.
    });
   }
  after1()
  {
    this.http.get("URL2").subscribe((res)=>{
      this.Request2result=res;
      this.after2(); // execution will move to the rest of the code only when both the requests are done.
    });
  }
  after2()
    {
    // rest of the code.
    console.log(this.Request1result);
    console.log(this.Request2result);

    }

}
```

Comment: better is to chain observables with flatMap()