# How to make a synchronous call in Angular 9? | geolocation

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, async-await, geolocation

The accepted solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605737/how-to-make-a-synchronous-call-in-angular-5) didn't work for me. I am making a call to a location service that needs to be synchronous because an api call is executed on it immediately thereafter.

My logging indicates that the location service is still returning `undefined` despite the await clause.

*service that makes api call*

```js
...
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
class PrepopulateService {
  constructor(private locationService: LocationService,
              private log: LoggerService) { }

  async prepopulate(): Promise<boolean> {
    const coords: string[] = await this.locationService.getLocation();
    console.log(coords)
    if(coords == null) {
      return false;
    }
    console.log(coords)
    // api call here
    return true;
  }
}

export { PrepopulateService }
```

*service that gets location for it*

```js
...
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
class LocationService {

  constructor(private log: LoggerService) { }

  getLocation(): Promise<string[]> {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        console.log([String(latitude), String(longitude)])
        return [String(latitude), String(longitude)];
      });
    } else {
      this.log.warn('No support for geolocation');
      return null;
    }
  }
}

export { LocationService }
```

What's wrong with my implementation of async/await?

Comment: From the looks of it, it seems you forgot return infront of `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {`
That getLocation doesn't return anything so if you try to use a value from it, it will give you undefined.

Comment: getting TS2332 type void not assignable to promise string, i think its a void method

Comment: is there a stateful solution, in light of that?

Comment: yeah you are getting that because of the if. All return paths doesn't return a promise according to the way you set it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning a promise from your `getLocation` function.

You should call `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` from within a promise and return that promise. You then resolve the promise within the callback you pass to `getCurrentPosition`.

```
getLocation(): Promise<string[]> {
  return new Promise<string[]>((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!navigator.geolocation) {
      reject(Error('No support for geolocation'));
      return;
    }

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      resolve([latitude.toString(), longitude.toString()]);
    });
  });
}
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r6kq9q (with mocked version of `getCurrentPosition`)

Comment: Always reject with an `Error()`

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Can you provide a source for this. I'm happy to edit, but can't find any definite info on this. My example matches case 3 from this site: https://mrcoles.com/javascript-promises-and-errors/ Not that I'm saying mrcoles.com is the authoritative source on promise rejection!

Comment: Kurt, it's just common sense. By rejecting/throwing a proper Error object, your deliberate throws emulate unexpected throws, thus the catch handler is unambiguously passed an Error (or RangeError etc), and (1) the need for exception handling in the catch handler is avoided; (2) the stack trace is made available.

Comment: And not just for Promises. Same applies to synchronous throw/catch.